# Java - regex to replace FIRST and LAST character with another one in ONE SHOT

Tags: java, regex

Consider i have this String here :

```
[Hel[don't change in the middle]lo]
```

How can i replace the first and last bracket with another character like this :

```
#Hel[don't change in the middle]lo#
```

I know this is possible like this :

```
String str = "[Hel[don't change in the middle]lo]";
str = str.replaceFirst("\\[", "#");
if (str.substring(str.length() - 1).equals("]")) {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + "#";
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

> Is there any other simple way using regex, so i can replace the first
>   and the last one in one shot?

like this :

```
str = str.replace("myregex");
```

Comment: Note: don't write `str.substring(str.length() - 1).equals("]"))`, this creates an unnecessary string. Use `str.charAt(str.length()-1) == ']'`.

Comment: mmm, thank you @AndyTurner this is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be enough:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^\\[(.*)]$", "#$1#"));
```

Comment: this show me `#Hel[don't change in the middle#lo#` and it change the last one and also change inside the String and this is not correct

Comment: Yep. I guess it's because the second `]` is not escaped. Seems to be fine otherwise.

Comment: The closing bracket doesn't need to be escaped @Izruo , the problem was a missing $ at the end to indicate end of string

Comment: Yea, if the closing bracket is always at the end of the input, that one will work, too.

Comment: You should add `^` also otherwise `f[o]o]` will be replaced with: `f#o]o#`

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
str = str.replaceAll("^\\[|]$", "#");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("^([^\\[]*)\\[|\\]([^\\]]*)$", "$1#$2");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QxKQUA/3)

Here we use alternation between 2 sub-matches that are:

- `^([^[]*)\\[` - matches 0 or more of characters followed by `[` at start
- `\\]([^]]*)$` - matches `]` followed by 0 or more of characters at end

**PS: This also takes care of some arbitrary characters before first `[` and last `]` in your input.**

Comment: this show me an error `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 20`

Comment: this still show me `#Hel[don't change in the middle#lo` if i don't use `#` in the end, it change the last one but in middle and this not correct

Comment: It is only changing first `[` and last `]`. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QxKQUA/4)

Comment: yes @anubhava i just should to check if the string start with that string and end with that, if not no need to change, for that i makes a condition `if (str.substring(str.length() - 1).equals("]")) {` if it end with that then replace it else no need

Comment: i think it gives the same result with @baao haha i don't find any difference

Comment: thnk you soo much ;)

Comment: Compare this [demo of baao's answer](https://regex101.com/r/QxKQUA/6) with [demo of Reimeus's answer](https://regex101.com/r/QxKQUA/5) to understand better

Comment: mmm, ok then you are correct ok i will accept the solution of baao then

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex if the operation is that simple:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.set(0, '#');
sb.set(str.length()-1, '#');
String result = sb.toString();
```

You can also write a single expression:

```
String result =
    new StringBuilder(str.length())
        .append('#')
        .append(str, 1, str.length()-1)
        .append('#')
        .toString();
```

If the characters to replace aren't at the beginning and end, search for them with `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`:

```
sb.set(str.indexOf('['), '#');
sb.set(str.lastIndexOf(']'), '#');
```

Comment: thank you @Andy Turner this can help others too in another case ;)